# Troubles using numpy on files from various origins

Tags: python, numpy

I have two txt files : one from UNIX and one from windows.
I parse these two files through the same process and get two variables : `unix` and `windows`. Both are lists of lists. For later calculations, I transform these variables into np.arrays. However, the final output is not the same.

Here is what `unix`'s content looks like :

```
np.array(unix)[-1][-1] = 'ship'
type(np.array(unix)[-1][-1]) = <type 'str'>
np.array(unix)[-1] = ['ship']
type(np.array(unix)[-1]) = <type 'list'>
```

Here is what `windows`' content looks like :

```
np.array(windows)[-1][-1] : 'ship'
type(np.array(windows)[-1][-1]) = <type 'numpy.string_'>
np.array(windows)[-1] : array(['ship'], dtype='|S5')
type(np.array(windows)[-1]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I suppose that this type difference is due to the different origin of the files. If that's the case, how can I convert windows-type documents into unix-like ?

### Update 2

Here is how I now read the files :

```
def read_my_file(file_path):
    result = []
    with codecs.open(file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            splitted_line= line.split(" ")
            result.append(splitted_line[1:])

    return result    
unix = read_my_file(unix_path)
windows = read_my_file(windows_path)
U = np.array(unix)
W = np.array(windows)
```

With this change, I now have

```
U[-1][-1] : u'ship'
type(U[-1][-1]) = <type 'unicode'>
U[-1] : [u'ship']
type(U[-1]) = <type 'list'>
U.dtype = dtype('O')

W[-1][-1] = u'ship'
type(W[-1][-1]) = <type 'numpy.unicode_'>
W[-1] = array([u'zola\r'], dtype='<U6')
type(W[-1]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
W.dtype = dtype('<U6')
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is here. Can you try and make it more clear? When you say *'This is what `unix` looks like'*, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You need to post the code you are using. I.e. how to you arrive at labels variable.

Comment: My bad, forgot to rename variables for clarity. Is that better ?

Comment: What are `unix.dtype` and `windows.dtype`?

Comment: My guess would be that it is a string encoding problem (check e.g., http://pymotw.com/2/codecs/ ). Numpy has also mechanisms to deal with string encodings (e.g., ``numpy.core.defchararray.decode
``). Never explicitly used those, so I cannot give any hints on that. To work around it, I use the ``codecs`` module when opening text files to ensure to always work with Unicode strings in my code.

Comment: @askewchan : 
`np.dtype(unix) and np.dtype(windows)` get me `Data type not understood`

@Dietrich : I tried to read files using `codecs` as you suggest, I edited my post.

Comment: @fxm, please type it as shown above: `unix.dtype` is not equivalent to `np.dtype(unix)`

Comment: @askewchan my bad :
`W.dtype = dtype('<U6')`

`U.dtype = dtype('O')` (`windows` and `unix` themselves don't have this attribute, they're just lists)

Comment: Hm.  And why aren't you just using numpy functions to load the files (`np.genfromtxt(file_path)`)? If you want to remove newlines or the first column, you can do that by slicing or reshaping the resultant array.

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware of this method :] 
Anyway, it works just fine wor the `unix` file, but I get an array full of `nan` for `windows`

Comment: Try specifying the dtype: `np.genfromtxt(file_path, dtype='U6')` (or possibly `'S6'` to try strings vs unicode)

Comment: I'm affraid I was wrong with `unix` before. Setting dtype makes `windows` read correctly but I have troubles with the `unix`file (number of columns is sometimes higher than the first line, causing errors). I'm looking on how to fix that.